# How to reload kernel module automatically if it fails to load

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules

How do I reload a kernel module automatically, if it fails?

I have a Wi-Fi Qualcom network card in my notebook, but sometimes it fails to load. I wrote a simple script I call `fixwifi`, that basically removes, waits, and then loads the module again:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
sleep 1
sudo modprobe ath10k_pci
```

The module in question sometimes fails on boot, sometimes on wake-up from sleep, and prints the following to the log (output from `dmesg`):

```
[   40.336212] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: wmi service ready event not received
[   40.426511] ath10k_pci 0000:07:00.0: Could not init core: -110
```

Currently, whenever I see the module fail, I open terminal and just do `fixwifi`... but it's manual labor which I assume could be automated.

Is there some way to automate the process (or, god, fix it?!)? I was thinking about writing a systemd unit, but how do I get notified about module fails? Do I constantly poll or watch system log?

**System:** Ubuntu 22.04 with systemd.
**Excerpt from `lshw`**:

```
*-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
                logical name: wlp7s0
                version: 31
                serial: ...
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=... latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:145 memory:a4000000-a41fffff
```

Comment: [This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=275914) seems to be thinking along the same lines, adding a delay/restart to NetworkManager fixed it.